# print first array element when it ends

Tags: java, arrays, printing

As the topic states and with my previous post

Which requires me to print 4 consecutive numbers in the array locations

I have managed to understand the code given to me. However Fast Snail comment made me thought about the program thoroughly and indeed got me thinking on how do I make the array print it's first location's element again.

As e.g (" Note " the array size is 20) The array location given to me is 18, the program will have to print the elements in location 19, 20, 1 ,2 . I have managed to understand on how to print elements in location 19 and 20 but I have no idea how to program it to print back to it's first position.

Thanks once again in advanced for any help given!

Comment: Remark: arrays are 0-indexed, so an array of size `20` has indices `0` to `19`. Question: What holds you back from simply accessing the first array element via `myArray[0]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mod operation with length of the array.

18 % 20 = 18
19 % 20 = 19
20 % 20 = 0 (first element of the array)
21 % 20 = 1

```
int firstPrint = 18;//or a random value

for(int i = firstPrint; i < firstPrint + 4; i++) {
    System.out.println(myArray[firstPrint % myArray.length]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)(`%`) to cycle within the range when you cross the boundary(array length - 1):

```
int[] arr = new int[20];
int startIndex = Math.random()*arr.length;


for(int i = startIndex; i < startIndex+4; i++) {
    System.out.println(arr[i%arr.length]);
}
```